# How to add '/' between two strings?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_location.FolderName))
{
    name = _location.FolderName + '/' + name;
}
```

Is it correct way to add `/` between two strings? Or I should use the following code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_location.FolderName))
{
    name = _location.FolderName + "/" + name;
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to get into very narrow details about how this is executed, those are equivalent. But anyway - use `Path.Combine` as suggested below.

Comment: Am I missing something or are these two code snippets identical?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something `'` vs. `"`.

Comment: @AntonGogolev One is using a `char` for the forward slash, and the other is using a `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` for this purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.pathseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
Console.WriteLine("Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar={0}", Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
Console.WriteLine("Path.DirectorySeparatorChar={0}", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
Console.WriteLine("Path.PathSeparator={0}", Path.PathSeparator);
Console.WriteLine("Path.VolumeSeparatorChar={0}", Path.VolumeSeparatorChar);
Console.Write("Path.GetInvalidPathChars()=");
foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
    Console.Write(c);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Will give result:

```
// Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar=/
// Path.DirectorySeparatorChar=\
// Path.PathSeparator=;
// Path.VolumeSeparatorChar=:
```

Comment: Did you mean that: `name = _location.FolderName + Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + name;`?

Comment: So if _location.FolderName already ends with / you add another /. Path.Combine is more fail safe on this.

Comment: @Steve it is safe to have // in path

Answer (score 12):

For concatenating file paths, you should use the `System.IO.Path.Combine` method instead.

```
using System.IO;
...

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_location.FolderName))
{
    name = Path.Combine(_location.FolderName, name);
}
```

One thing to note, as Anton mentioned in the comments below is that you must ensure that the characters in the paths are valid, you can find more information in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Where is separator character ('/')? It will be automatically added?

Comment: It will be automatically added by the `Combine` method. It really is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @MikeEason It should be noted that `Combine()` fails when there are invalid characters in path "fragments".

Comment: It's also worth noting that this will combine the paths using `\\`` rather than `/`, so it will give a different result to the question as asked.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Which is a pretty darn good behaviour when you're trying to obtain a valid path as the output :)

Comment: @decPL How is `Path.Combine("com1", "com2")` a _valid_ path?

Comment: @AntonGogolev it's a valid (if relative) path, at least where I come from :)

Comment: @decPL This path cannot possibly exist on Windows (without resorting to [the \\?\ prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#win32_file_namespaces)). Back to my point: `Combine()` checks that there are no illegal _characters_ in fragments, yet it does not check that the path itself is at all legal.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Do read up on relative vs absolute path - both are valid and both will point to a specific place (though relative will depend on the execution environment). Which I'm afraid makes your point moot (i.e. `Path.Combine()`, at least in your simple examples, will always give a **valid** path).

Comment: @decPL See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx): "Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file: ...COM1, COM2, ... ". Which makes one question why exactly `Combine()` disallows illegal characters, yet it allows paths with reserved file names.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that's an invalid **windows** path? Fair enough - but disallowing those altogether seems limiting IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Use double back slash it will help

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_location.FolderName))
{
    name = _location.FolderName + "\\" + name;
}
```

Comment: This will give you two forward slashes.  How does that help?